# Establishing connection of SQL Server 2008 with VS2012 project via web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to connect my database from my SQL Server to my asp.net project through the `web.config` file. I found code like this which should be able to connect my SQL Server and ASP.net project together properly. However after adding this code, I got this error.

This is my SQL Server connection string that is supposed to be place in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=sergio-desktop\sqlexpress;Initial 
                          Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=userName;Password=password"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And this is the error

[image]

I'm also not very sure if the syntax of my connection string to establish connection between the two is correct.

Comment: are u writing this in system.web block???

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, the connection element should not go in `system.web` section. it should go in `configuration` section of your `web.config`

as

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
---
```